# Alignment issues with std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I finally ran into the annoying issue described here:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html

I have a structure containing several Eigen fixed-size matrices, and i want to store several instances of my structure in a std::vector. So obviously 'These issues arise only with fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types and structures having such Eigen objects as member.' applies. However, it is only described how to solve the issue with vectors directly collecting Eigen Objects, not with structures containing Eigen instances.

Currently my problem looks like this:

```
struct MyStruct{
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW //Don't know if this applies here
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> A;
    // several more instances and stuff here
    MyStruct ( ...)  // constructor taking several arguments, but only running an initilization list for some members

    // no destructor defined / implemented !

    // no methods!
}

//
MyStruct instanceStruct( .. constructing .. );
instanceStruct.A = someAssigment() ; 
// this type of 'instancing' before i push it into the vector is necessary ...

std::vector<MyStruct> myVector;
myVector.push_back( std::move( instanceStruct ) ); // gdb tells me that here we run into a SIGSEGV
```

What causes the problem? Thank you!

Comment: what compiler are you using ? AFAIK, in c++17, everything *should* work out of the box, without EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW or the like ...

Comment: gcc 7.2 (arch linux), with -march=native. Without -march=native, (and thus, without vectorization), everything works fine

Comment: ok, but have you tried "-std=c++17" ?

Comment: That works, thank you! Hoiwever, what can i do for for C++11 standard?

Comment: in c++11, you'll need to use eigen provided allocator along with its eigen provided vector specialization. It's ugly, I know. Either that, or you disable vectorization, or you store MyStruct as a unique_ptr inside another struct that you can then pass to vector... even so, you still need special care to avoid UB when copying eigen objects around ... I'll write a more elaborate answer later...

Comment: the solutions described in your link also apply to your case, so you  need to use an aligned allocator (or disable alignment)

Comment: Can you please provide me a hint for the present example? I thought adding the macro ' EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW '  should be sufficient for structs containing Eigen members?

Comment: for the future, use @name-of-poster when you post a comment; in this way, we know to who you're talking and, above all, 'name-of-poster' will be notified accordingly ...

Answer (score 3):

#### From C++17 on

The default allocator used by standard containers is required to respect alignment, and so are variables of any storage duration (*). Therefore, your code should work out-of-the-box in this case, because Eigen do specify alignment where needed.

(*) there are *caveats* though:

- an implementation may still throw bad_alloc or refuse to compile definitions where an unsupported alignment is requested. But, as far as I know, it cannot fail silently, nor result in undefined behavior.
- user defined allocators are allowed to silently ignore *over-aligned* types. Moreover, beware that pre-C++17 libraries may make assumptions internally, circumventing the aforementioned guarantees. In general, you should always check for over-aligned type support for any facility allocating types (possibly internally).

#### From C++11 on

The only(*) thing you should worry about are variables of dynamic storage duration obtained either via new or the default allocator (see [P0035r4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html) for more details).

Now, Eigen fixes both by providing EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW and
Eigen::aligned_allocator:

```
struct MyStruct{
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW // this will make new MyStruct to work
//...

// this will make vector (or any other allocator-aware container) to work
std::vector<MyStruct,Eigen::aligned_allocator<MyStruct> >
```

note that, contrary to what the official doc says, you can use any aligned allocator in C++11, so there's no need to `#include<Eigen/StdVector>` (you must include it if compiling in pre-C++11 mode though, or if your compiler does not fully support c++11 alignment semantics).

Alternatively, you can disable vectorization (see Eigen macro doc to see how) or allocate vectorizable matrices only via new:

```
struct MyStructImpl{
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    // vectorizable matrices ...
};

struct MyStruct
{
  MyStructImpl* aligned_data_; // possibly a unique_ptr<MyStructImpl>
  // copy-move-assign accordingly ...
  // non-vectorizable matrices and other data ...
};

std::vector<MyStruct> v; // ok !
```

this will cost you an heap allocation and less memory locality, but will make cheaper to move MyStruct around. So, it may turn out faster or slower, depending on your use case.