# Child class alignment requirements different than base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, memory-alignment

I am working with a very simple structure that contains only a few double.

Let's call it A:

```
struct A {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

On my computer, using clang++10.0.1, the alignment requirements of this struct is 8 bytes (`alignof(A) == 8`).

This struct is inherited from by a second struct:

```
struct B : public A {
    Eigen::Quaternion<double> quat;
};
```

Eigen quaternions need to be aligned to work correctly. Since C++17, this is handled by the compiler, so nothing to do here.

Alignment requirements of B is 32 bytes (`alignof(B) == 32`).

---

In my code, I build a vector of B, then pass a reference to this vector to a function where I iterate over the B instances. And I get a segfault.

```
std::vector<B> vec;
// doing stuff with vec, filling it with data
// vec and its content are perfectly valid here
doStuff(vec);
```

```
void doStuff(std::vector<B>& inOut) {
    for(const B& p: inOut) {
        // I try to access an element of B, I get a segfault here
        auto copy = p.x;
    }
}
```

There is no multi-threading involved, my vector can't have been updated from outside.

When I ran this code in gdb, my loop variable `p` was completely broken (vptr is null and all values are 0). But what's weird, is that if I inspect the vector before calling `doStuff`, it is perfectly ok. But inside `doStuff`, it is broken.

UBSAN tells me:

```
stl_iterator.h:969:16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0x7fb0eace6010 for type 'B', which requires 32 byte alignment
0x7fb0eace6010: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00  b8 31 76 a9 b1 7f 00 00  b0 72 33 94 a4 9c 49 42  00 00 8f 88 b4 33 51 40  00 10 e2 8e
              ^ 
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior stl_iterator.h:969:16 in 
doStuff.cpp:2: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0x7fb0eace6010 for type 'const B', which requires 32 byte alignment
0x7fb0eace6010: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00  b8 31 76 a9 b1 7f 00 00  b0 72 33 94 a4 9c 49 42  00 00 8f 88 b4 33 51 40  00 10 e2 8e
              ^ 
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior doStuff.cpp:2 in 
doStuff.cpp:3: runtime error: upcast of misaligned address 0x7fb0eace6010 for type 'B', which requires 32 byte alignment
0x7fb0eace6010: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00  b8 31 76 a9 b1 7f 00 00  b0 72 33 94 a4 9c 49 42  00 00 8f 88 b4 33 51 40  00 10 e2 8e
              ^ 
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior doStuff.cpp:3: in 
doStuff.cpp:3: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x7fb0eace6010 for type 'A', which requires 32 byte alignment
0x7fb0eace6010: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00  b8 31 76 a9 b1 7f 00 00  b0 72 33 94 a4 9c 49 42  00 00 8f 88 b4 33 51 40  00 10 e2 8e

==33989==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x0000000000a4 (pc 0x7fb1a8d187bf bp 0x7fb1a9763158 sp 0x7fb1727ec240 T34466)
==33989==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==33989==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7fb1a8d187bf in __dynamic_cast /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/dyncast.cc:50:15
    #1 0x55a9ee96a6a5 in __ubsan::checkDynamicType(void*, void*, unsigned long)
    #2 0x55a9ee9695c3 in HandleDynamicTypeCacheMiss(__ubsan::DynamicTypeCacheMissData*, unsigned long, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions)
    #3 0x55a9ee969c70 in __ubsan_handle_dynamic_type_cache_miss
    #4 0x7fb1ac1c75d8 in doStuff(std::vector<B, std::allocator<B> >&) doStuff.cpp:29:35
```

So, this looks like an alignment issue. It is expecting A to be 32 bytes aligned while it is actually aligned with 8 bytes ("member access within misaligned address xxx for type 'A', which requires 32 byte alignment"). If I force `A` to 32 bytes alignments (using `alignas(32)`), everything works, but I'm not sure if I fixed the problem or just the symptom.

I do not understand why accessing `A::x` using a reference to a `B` needs to go through the vptr (member variables should be local?). And I do not understand why alignment requirements of B are applied to A when accessing its member variables from a B reference. I really don't understand the issue to begin with.

Is my fix (manually aligning the base struct) enough to fix the problem or is there a bigger underlying issue ? Is there any resource that talks about this ? (alignment requirements of member variables and inheritance) ?

That's a lot of questions. Sorry for that.

---

Edit 1: Something I just noticed, the .cpp file where the function is declared is in a different library than the one that calls it. Could it be a linker issue ? Or something that is compiled differently on the two libraries (all the internal libraries of my project share the same compiler options though).

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Do you really compile with `-std=c++17`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52000359/580083) may be related. Also, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47364311/580083).

Comment: @idclev463035818 I can't reproduce it outside of my code, I tried many things, it always works. So my question is not a "fix my code" question, it's a "fix my understanding of how this should work" question, which, I think, does not require a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, I am sure the code is compiled with C++17 since I heavily use other C++17 features in the same file

Comment: @Ebatsin If you cannot reproduce the problem outside of your code, then, the problem is likely somewhere else in this code. As for debugging, you say that if you put a breakpoint right before the function call, there the vector is perfectly fine. And once you step into the function, it is broken? That sounds really weird, when no operation is performed in between except passing an argument by reference.

Comment: @DanielLangr no, the inOut argument is correct. if I do `*inOut.begin()`, I get a valid point. The point is invalid in the for each loop (ie. `inOut` is valid and its content is valid, but `p` is invalid). Which makes no sense

Comment: @Ebatsin Could you show us the whole code of that function? Or, just the lines before the loop.

Comment: "**[allocator.requirements]/10** If the alignment associated with a specific over-aligned type is not supported by an allocator, instantiation of the allocator for that type may fail. The allocator also may **silently ignore** the requested alignment." Emphasis mine. Perhaps this is what happens in your case.

Comment: @DanielLangr This is the whole code in this function (it was longer  but I could reduce it to this). I also just noticed that if I define the function in the header, it works, so this has nothing to do with the function itself. But if defined in the cpp it does not work. It is worth noting that this cpp file is part of a different lib than the one than calls it. I edited my original message to reflect this

Comment: @Ebatsin It seems to be an ABI issue. Do you compile the library and the program with the same compiler? Note that even different implementations of the C++ standard lib (such as libstdc++ and libc++) might not be compatible due to different definitions of `std::vector`.

Comment: It's compiled with the same compiler options, with the same compiler (clang 10.0.1 using libstdc++ (from GCC 10.2.0). Linked with lld). Only differences I see could come from the libraries used during compilation (mainly Eigen and PCL).