# Segfault with Eigen::Vector3f in a std::vector

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I am using the PCL, and in the greedy meshing component it uses Eigen::Vector3f to hold the points, but I am getting segfaults when the object (gp3) is being destructed.

The definition of the object itself which causes the segfault:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector3f> > coords_;
```

I am running the reconstruct() method, and when it reaches the line

```
coords_.reserve (indices_->size ());
```

and I exit the function, it causes the memory fault. According to https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html this looks like the proper definition of the vector. I checked `indices_->size()`, which is at around 55k, which is a normal value for a pointcloud, and should work fine.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Certain classes of Eigen require special alignment depending on what optimization is enabled.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Alignment issues with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47364311/7478597)

Comment: Check if there are no conflicting versions of Eigen in your machine. E.g. it is possible that PCL is compiled with one version, and in your project you use the system headers from other version.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [mre]?

Comment: Please provide [mcve], it is [impossible to reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/sTf9hv) with data provided.

Comment: Its kind of hard, I tried creating something just using those lines, but it wouldn't crash. It happens within the Pointcloud Library when calling that reconstruction method, but if I just use random samples on similar lines, no crash unfortunately. Not sure exactly why though.